# Using Search Replace for Multiple File Get Contents Param

Tags: php, replace, file-get-contents

Working on an April Fools joke with a friend. Basically, we are `file_get_contents();` a local newspaper article and performing a `str_replace();` for specific name and image URL. It doesn't even matter what we are replacing, the problem I face is performing more than one search / replace value.

I wrote two functions each with it's own variables and search / replace, only the first works. I'm scratching my head on how to get more than one search / replace value. Below I have the basic code I'm working with. How can I add multiple search / replace?

```
// Let's April Fool!
$readfile = 'URL-police-searching-for-bank-robbery-suspect';
$pull = file_get_contents($readfile);
$suspectname = 'Suspect Name';
$newname = 'New Name';
echo str_replace($suspectname, $newname, $pull);
```

I want to search / replace things on the page such as name, img src URL, etc. It doesn't matter what I'm replacing, I can work out the details if I can just get more than one search / replace.

Thank you!

Comment: You could make an array that works like a dictionary by mapping keys (words to be replaced) with values (what should be written instead): `$arr = array("suspect" => "friend_name");`. You then loop through this array and redefine `$pull` for every iteration: `$pull = str_replace($key, $value, $pull);`. Search "how to iterate an array in php" or similar to get examples and the correct syntax.

Comment: @jDo Would that work for image urls? Those aren't exactly words.

Comment: @jamerson Sure, it would work in the sense that any matching strings found, including URLs, would be replaced with whatever value you have under that key in the array. It's a pretty hardcoded solution since you'd have to put all the URLs or URL substrings in the array but it'll work

Comment: @jDo Excellent. First thing at the office I will put it to work. I only need to replace maybe three or four things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do sophisticated replacement that takes grammar and natural language into consideration, you'd need something more complex. But for simple search and replace, this'll work fine:

```
<?php

$pull = "the suspect was last seen wearing a black hoodie and trainers. Have you seen this man? www.local_police.com/bank_robber.jpg";
echo $pull . "\n";

$dictionary = array("the suspect" => "friend_name", "hoodie" => "swimsuit", "trainers" => "adult diaper", "www.local_police.com/bank_robber.jpg" => "www.linkedlin.com/friend_profile_pic.jpg" );

foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value){
    $pull = str_replace($key, $value, $pull);
}

echo $pull . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
user@box:~/$ php prank.php 
the suspect was last seen wearing a black hoodie and trainers. Have you seen this man? www.local_police.com/bank_robber.jpg
friend_name was last seen wearing a black swimsuit and adult diaper. Have you seen this man? www.linkedlin.com/friend_profile_pic.jpg
```

Comment: It reads brilliance. I will test and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: what you provided pointed me in the right direction. I'm going to post an answer reflecting the basic syntax I came up with. I'm not sure if SE will have a problem with hotlinking to a full write up, but here goes. http://adopttheweb.com/2016/03/31/april-fools-joke-using-file-get-contents/

Comment: @jarmerson Nice :) I'll make sure to look out for this maniac! Thanks for the credit btw.

Comment: In my code `.'\n'` wasn't necessary and shows up at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @jarmerson Yeah, that was just for printing the output on separate lines; not a part of the actual code necessary to get the job done. Maybe I should've mentioned that. "\n" (newline) isn't recognized in html but will show up in your terminal. To get the equivalent in html, you'd append a `'<br>'` or `<br/>`  for line **br**eak

Comment: I read up on that and understand exactly how it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

@jDo answered my question and got me started, but I want to share the final product. Here's what I came up with:

```
//
// Using file_get_contents(); in an array   
//
//
// Define the file we want to get contents from in a variable
//
$readfile = 'http://adomainname.com/page/etc';
//
// Variable to read the contents of our file into a string
//
$pull = file_get_contents($readfile);
//
//
// Define stuff to be replaced
//
$find_stuff = 'Find Stuff';
$replace_stuff = 'Replace Stuff';
$find_more_stuff = 'Find More Stuff';
$replace_more_stuff  = 'Replace More Stuff';
//
// Variable to create the array that stores multiple values in one single variable
//
$find_replace = [ // Let's start our array
                $find_stuff => $replace_stuff,
                $find_more_stuff => $replace_more_stuff,
                ];// Close the array

//
// This is where the magic happens
//
foreach ($find_replace as $key => $value){ // Now we take our array of each key and value
$pull = str_replace($key, $value, $pull); // Will look for matched keys and replace them with our new values 
}

echo $pull; // That's it
```